# How to select first row from table after change using JQuery?

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc

I want to select first row from table after change using JQuery. `ABC` is dropdown and when user change in dropdown, it loads another set of data in table.

JQuery

```
  $('#ABC').change(function () {
        let data = {
             abc: $('#ABC').val()                
         }
      var url = '@Url.Action("Partial", "S")'
        $('#SPartial').load(url, data)
$('#SPartial').find('#tbl tbody tr:first').addClass('select');
    });
```

parent view

```
<div id="SPartial">                  
  @Html.RenderPartial("_Partial", Model);                
 </div>
```

partial view

```
<table class="table", id="tbl">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>@Html.DisplayNameFor(m => m.D)</th>
            <th>@Html.DisplayNameFor(m => m.R)</th>
            <th></th>         
        </tr>
    </thead>

    @foreach (var item in Model)
    {
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.D)

                </td>

                <td>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.R)                 
                </td>

            </tr>
        </tbody>

     }
</table>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ajax (your `.load()` function) is async, and your `$('#SPartial').find('#tbl tbody tr:first').addClass('select');` line of code is being executed before the partial view is returned and loaded in the DOM.

You need to execute that line of code in the success callback

```
var partial = $('#SPartial'); // cache it
$('#ABC').change(function () {
    let data = { abc: $('#ABC').val() };
    var url = '@Url.Action("Partial", "S")'
    partial.load(url, data, function(response) {
        partial.find('#tbl tbody tr:first').addClass('select');
    });
});
```

Comment: Awesome Stephen! very elegant solution. Thank you.